# Xcode Build error with one spec. Library: ld: library not found for -lzbar

Tags: ios, xcode, shared-libraries

I checked out a working app from SVN. Want to test it in iphone simulator. But the building failed.

```
Ld /Users/ludwig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySoftware-eclocsslmbcdgibhlruzhzsnyctb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MySoftware.de.app/MySoftware.de normal i386
    cd /Users/ludwig/MySoftware_SVN/MySoftware/trunk/MobileClient/iOS/MySoftware
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/ludwig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySoftware-eclocsslmbcdgibhlruzhzsnyctb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/ludwig/MySoftware_SVN/MySoftware/trunk/MobileClient/iOS/MySoftware/ZBarSDK -L/Users/ludwig/MySoftware_SVN/MySoftware/trunk/MobileClient/iOS/MySoftware -F/Users/ludwig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySoftware-eclocsslmbcdgibhlruzhzsnyctb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/ludwig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySoftware-eclocsslmbcdgibhlruzhzsnyctb/Build/Intermediates/MySoftware.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MySoftware.build/Objects-normal/i386/MySoftware.de.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=4.3 -framework Security -framework MessageUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework QuartzCore -liconv -framework AVFoundation -lzbar -o /Users/ludwig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySoftware-eclocsslmbcdgibhlruzhzsnyctb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MySoftware.de.app/MySoftware.de

ld: library not found for -lzbar
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can somebody help? Or need more information?!

I am not able to add a screenshot..
in the overview of the "other sources" there is the dict ZBarSDK and inside there is  a headers and a resources folder and a file:
libzbar.a but the filename is in Red!? and i am not able to open it. Is this maybe the reason?

Comment: It seems that the ZBar library was not commited to SVN, you should download it and include it to your project. http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/iPhoneSDK/ZBarSDK-1.2.dmg/download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a particular way to install ZBAR. Follow these instructions : http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/install.html

Comment: Thank you, this was is. although the files were already in source folder this solved the problem!

Comment: oddly enough, restarting xcode did it for me (the library was already in place)